# Is the pointwise minimum of functions a smooth function?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Consider $U\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $n\ge 2$ an open subset and $f_1,f_2\in C^\infty(U)$ two positive functions. Define $\psi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+$ as $\psi(u):=min\{f_1(x),f_2(x)\}$, $\psi$ is clearly continuous.

Suppose $p\in U$ is such that $f_1(p)=f_2(p)$. Question: **does there exist an open neighborhood $U_p\subset U$ of $p$ such that $\psi$ is $C^1$ on $U_p$?**

I already have an answer, I hope you can tell me if I'm right or not.

I think $\psi$ can't be $C^1$ on any $U_p$. The equation $f_1-f_2=0$ describes an hypersurface $H$ of $U_p$ and $U_p\setminus H$ is a union of connected components on which $f_1<f_2$ or $f_2<f_1$. So there is a side of $U_p\setminus H$ on which $\psi=f_1$ and a side of $U_p\setminus H$ on which $\psi=f_2$. By this we get that if $\frac{\partial}{\partial v}{f_1}_p\neq\frac{\partial}{\partial v}{f_2}_p$ for every $\vec v\in T_pH$ then $\psi$ can't be $C^1(U_p)$.

Am i right?

Comment: What if $f_1 = f_2$?

Comment: According to the conditions of the statement it is possible to have $f_1$ be greater on the entire neighborhood of $p$, so you can't split up the neighborhood this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems to your proof.

First of all, $H$ might not be nonempty. Indeed, if $f_1 > f_2$ or $f_2 > f_1$ then $\psi$ is smooth (and in this case $H$ is empty).

Secondly, even if $H$ is a nice hypersurface, there are cases where $H$ does not divide $U$ into $\{f_1 > f_2\}$ and $\{f_1<f_2\}$. For example, when

$$f_1(x, y) = x^2+1, f_2(x, y) = 2x^2+1,$$

then $H = \{ f_1 - f_2 = 0\}$ is the $y$-axis but on each sides of $H$, both $f_2 > f_1$.

Even worse, it might happens that even $H$ is a nice hyperplane and divide $U$ into $\{f_1>f_2\}$ and $\{f_2 >f_1\}$, the function $\psi $ can still be smooth: an example are

$$ f_1(x, y) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/x^2} +1&\text{if } x>0 \\ 1 &\text{if }x\le 0 \end{cases} ,\ \ \ f_2(x, y) = f_1(-x, y).$$

I hope it is now clear that the statement is actually false.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't consider the case $H$ doesn't divide $U$ in $\{f_1>f_2\}$ and $\{f_2>f_1\}$. But for $f_1=x+1$ and $f_2=-x+1$ then $\psi$ isn't $C^1$, right? so I guess the condition for the smoothness of $\psi$ is $\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial v}$